# why not able to define a method inside of run() method of thread

Tags: java, multithreading

the first example is possible, but example 2 is not possible and results in "illegal start of expression" error message from the compiler.  why is it not possible to define a method inside of the run() method?

example 1

```
 public class TextUpdater implements Runnable {

    public void inter(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        inter();

    }

   }
}
```

example 2, not possible

```
 public class TextUpdater implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

       public void inter(){  // results in error

       }

   }
}
```

Comment: This does not compile for a reason: It is illegal.

Comment: This may be perfectly legal in other languages, but not in Java.

Comment: Umm ... this is a bit like asking why a bicycle doesn't have wings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function within a function- Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097275/function-within-a-function-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually declare a method within a method it will always result in an error. Java is strictly object-oriented and it requires methods to belong to a class. In other words, you have to declare your methods in class. JavaScript, Python and other object-oriented languages loosen this strict rule, but Java does not. Read [this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097275/function-within-a-function-java). It is almost exactly the same topic.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not let you define a method inside a method. It doesn't even have any semantic rules for what that would do. What are you expecting example 2 to do?

It's clear what example 1 does. You create a method called `inter` with an empty body. Then, in `run`, you call it.

But what should 2 do? You create a method `inter` inside `run`. So what would that do? When would you call it?

Comment: +1 for the questions, actually those are answers :)

Comment: this is a good answer in the way of classic philosophy

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot [define a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to create a method inside another method.

Answer (score 0):

run() is a method, you just can not define new methods inside a method.
Methods are defining in class section not inside methods