# switch doesn't work with AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, switch-statement

Seems like the displayView variable is not compatible with void, i try to add a progress dialog into a navigation drawer, every time that an element its selected

```js
public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
     private Context context;
     ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

     public AsyncClass(Context cxt) {
         context = cxt;
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
         dialog.show();
     }
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
      
      public void displayView(int position) { /*the message here is :void is an invalid type for the variable displayView*/

       
       
       Fragment fragment = null;
       switch (position) { 
       
       case 1:
        fragment = new  HomeFragment();
        break;
       case 2:
        fragment = new  CalendarioFragment();
        break;
       case 5:
        fragment = new  ContactoFragment();
        break;
       case 6:
        fragment = new  OnclickFragment();
        break;
       default:
        break;
       }

       if (fragment != null) {
        try{
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and tit|le, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
         Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
       } 
       else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
       }
      }
      SystemClock.sleep(2000);
         return (null);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

it says "void is an invalid type for the variable displayView"

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Java` doesn't support nested methods, which you are doing in `doInBackground()`. This is the reason for given error. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388601/2571277) in details.

Another thing is that,  `doInBackground()` will be running on background thread so don't update UI from there. `AsyncTask` is used only for long running operations. You can consider moving you `doInBackground()` code to relevant `Activity` or `Fragment`.