# Why can't this method be called inside actionListener?

Tags: java

I'm new to learning about methods in java. In python, it was easy to use "Functions" but I recently learnt that java doesn't have something similar to that. I have a method which should return the lowest value out of n1 and n2. I'm getting an error in the line public static int minFunction...

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "(", ; 
 expected
- Syntax error on token ",", ; 
 expected
- Syntax error on token ")", ; 
 expected
```

But there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the syntax.

```
JButton btnCompute = new JButton("Compute");
    btnCompute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try { 


                int n1=5;
                int n2=4;
                int minValue= minFunction(n1,n2);


                public static int minFunction(int n1 , int n2) {
                       int min;
                       if (n1 > n2)
                          min = n2;
                       else
                          min = n1;

                       return min; 
                    }                       
                }

            catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot define methods within methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Java support inner / local / sub methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388584/does-java-support-inner-local-sub-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call method from listener implementation, put it out side implementation. For example,

```
JButton btnCompute = new JButton("Compute");
public void handleAction() {
    btnCompute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                int n1 = 5;
                int n2 = 4;
                int minValue = minFunction(n1, n2);

            }

            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

            }
        }
    });
}
public int minFunction(int n1, int n2) {
    int min;
    if (n1 > n2)
        min = n2;
    else min = n1;

    return min;
}
```