# Java - metode inside a metode syntax issues

Tags: java, syntax

Really don't know what it's called so I'm having a hard time searching for the answer.
Anyhow, I want to make a metode with metode inside (if that's even possible?).

```
public void log() {
    public makeLogElement() {
       //making a logelement to write inn
    }

    public write(String text) {
       logelement.setText(logelement.getText() + text);
    }
}
log myLog = new log();
myLog.makeLogElement();
myLog.write("This'll be written in the log");
```

What is the right syntax for making something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388584/does-java-support-inner-local-sub-methods

Comment: it's not possible you can't create object of method.

Comment: Just imagine how you can invoke this.     . log().write()

Comment: You can define java.util.function.Function (java 8+) inside method and use it localy. Thats all you can do.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. But you can create a class inside a method.