# Can i add an ActionListener() inside a main method or any method?

Tags: java, actionlistener

```
public void Message() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello it is working");
}

}
```

//Message() is a method inside a class.

Comment: You cannot declare methods inside methods in Java, so the code you posted above is invalid.

Comment: In order for your example to work, you'd need to `implement ActionListener`, otherwise you'll get a compiler error

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, and why you want to put an *ActionListener* inside *any method*.

Comment: @Jesper an *ActionListener* is not a method.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking about an anonymous class, something like this:  `comp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){...}});`?

Comment: ...or a lambda: `comp.addActionListener(evt->{...});`?

Answer (score 0):

All methods must be declared inside a class separately. In simple terms, methods are something the object of a certain class can do, and defining them inside another method does not make sense. So in your case,

```
public void Message (){

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello it is working");
}
```

Edit: This post is worth a read. I have no knowledge about lambda expressions, but it could be what you're looking for :)
[Does Java support inner / local / sub methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388584/does-java-support-inner-local-sub-methods)

Answer (score 0):

No. We cannot create nested methods in java. 
Try reading about [actionlisteners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) . :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 methods can be nested using lambdas.
Can methods in java be nested[...]?
No, that's not possible.

The closest thing you can get is:

```
class Name {
    void methodOne() {
        class InnerClass {
           void methodTwo() {
           }
         }
     }
 }
```

That is, a second method defined in a inner class defined in a method.

You can declare the method static inside the inner class, so you do not have to call new